# How to change router isReady in next app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I am transitioning from page router to app router in next.js. I read from next.js documentation that router.isReady is no longer required, how do I modify the following code to app router if I am not using searchParams in it?

As you can see from the last line `enabled: router.isReady`, what should be replaced if router.isReady is no longer available?

```
useQuery({
    queryKey: ['validateSetPassword', uniqueKey, email],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (uniqueKey && email) {
        try {
          const response = await validateSetPasswordApi(uniqueKey, email)
          setValidKey(true)
          return response
        } catch (error) {
          setValidKey(false)
          return null
        }
      } else {
        router.push('/login')
      }
    },
    onSuccess: (validateSetPassword: any) => {
      if (validateSetPassword) {
        formik.values.firstName = validateSetPassword.data.firstName
        formik.values.lastName = validateSetPassword.data.lastName
        formik.values.email = email
        setData(validateSetPassword)
      }
    },
    enabled: router.isReady
  })
```

or in useEffect use case

```
useEffect(() => {
    const token = searchParams.get('token')
    setToken(token)
  }, [router.isReady])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Next.js routing with `useRouter` hook, the `isReady` property is typically no longer needed because data fetching methods like `getServerSideProp`s or `getStaticProps` handle the readiness of data before rendering the page.

However, if you're migrating to the new `useQuery` hook from `next/navigation`, you can usually just remove the `enabled: router.isReady` line, and the query will be enabled by default when the component mounts. The router's state should be ready when the component is rendered.

Here is how you can modify your useQuery call:

```
useQuery({
queryKey: ['validateSetPassword', uniqueKey, email],
queryFn: async () => {
  if (uniqueKey && email) {
    try {
      const response = await validateSetPasswordApi(uniqueKey, email)
      setValidKey(true)
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      setValidKey(false)
      return null
    }
  } else {
    router.push('/login')
  }
},
onSuccess: (validateSetPassword: any) => {
  if (validateSetPassword) {
    formik.values.firstName = validateSetPassword.data.firstName
    formik.values.lastName = validateSetPassword.data.lastName
    formik.values.email = email
    setData(validateSetPassword)
  }
},
  // Remove the enabled line entirely
  // enabled: router.isReady
})
```

For the useEffect use case, you can also remove the dependency on router.isReady:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const token = searchParams.get('token')
  setToken(token)
}, []) // Removed [router.isReady]
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I thought about removing it like you did there, but I'm unsure if it would work as is. Thanks for your comment, cheers!